Pushing changes in Git: "Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged"
Following this tutorial, I created my own jekyll website hosted by github. I used a different template, namely this one, however. I forked this template, installed git, and cloned the repository into a folder called "Website" on my computer. I personalized the template in the "Website"-folder and was able to preview it using bundle exec jekyll serve.
Then I wanted to get my website up and running. The command git status showed the changes I expected. I then wrote git add <some file shown in git status>, git commit and then git push. At some point I got the error message:

Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.

I tried various things. I wrote git reset --hard origin/master. This reset all local changes. Luckily, in case anything went wrong, I had copied the "Website"-folder beforehand. I deleted the reset folder and kept the copy of the original folder, renaming it "Website".
Now, when I cd to this folder and write git status, I again get the error:

Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)


nothing to commit, working tree clean

How do I get my website up and running?
The git pull command gives "fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches."
git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all gives:
* 134a607c (HEAD -> master) First release of my website.
| * f4a6e184 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Fix repo card heigth for different repo descriptions (#2525) 
|/


git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all will show you the true state of your repository. Or use a visualization tool like GitKraken.

Did you git pull or git fetch?

@Schwern Thank you! It gives: "* 134a607c (HEAD -> master) First release of my website.
| * f4a6e184 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Fix repo card heigth for different repo descriptions (#2525)
|/ .[ ...]" How does that help?

Thank you for the info, but that's not readable in a comment. Please edit it into your question using code formatting so it can be understood.

Are you sure that's all git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all output? Because it looks like you're missing a commit. 134a607c and f4a6e184 should have a common ancestor commit.

"Diverged" means your local master and the remote's master have different commits. Since you've cloned, someone has pushed a commit to master. Let's walk through it.
Your remote looks like this:
remote
A - B - C [master]

A, B, and C are existing commits. master points at commit C. You make a clone.
remote
A - B - C [master]

local
A - B - C [master][origin/master]

origin/master is a remote tracking branch which remembers where master was on the remote (named "origin" by default) the last time you looked. Git does not use the network without your say so (pull, push, fetch).
At some point, someone pushed a commit to master. This is commit f4a6e184 in your repo. We'll call that commit D.
remote
A - B - C - D [master]

local
A - B - C [master][origin/master]

Your local repo does not see that change. Locally, you make a commit. This is commit 134a607c in your repo. Let's call that commit 4.
remote
A - B - C - D [master]

local
A - B - C - 4 [master][origin/master]

At some point, Git gets an update of the state of your remote (origin). It updates origin/master.
remote
A - B - C - D [master]

local
A - B - C - D [origin/master]
         \
          4 [master]

When you try to git push, Git will not let you because your branches have diverged. Your commits are not on top of origin/master. git push will not merge them for you. You have to merge origin/master into your master and then push.
$ git switch master
$ git merge origin/master

remote
A - B - C - D [master]

local
A - B - C - D [origin/master]
         \   \
          4 - M [master]

Now you can push.

Normally, git pull will merge for you. By default, git pull is git fetch (which updates origin/master) plus git merge origin/master. But your Git is not fully configured. You should have gotten a bunch of hints about how to fix this.
I recommend git config pull.rebase merges. This will change git pull so it does a git fetch and then a git rebase origin/master. This will rewrite your commits on top of the remote commits. This avoids a lot of unnecessary merges that just complicate your history.
$ git config pull.rebase merges
$ git pull

remote
A - B - C - D [master]

local
A - B - C - D [origin/master]
             \
              4A [master]

This makes for a cleaner, linear history with no "update merges".

Thank you for taking the time. When I try git merge origin/master, it says "error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: [...]"

@Anna And it should have told you how to fix that. Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches. Either commit your changes, stash them for later, or throw out the changes.
